# Matlab: como escrever uma função que recebe um numero n e retorna P = 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1))

Tags: funções, matlab

Como poderia criar uma função chamada repeat_prod(n) que recebe um numero n e retorna essa função P = 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1))

Estou com dificuldades de compreender como essa função deveria ser e agradeço qualquer direcionamento.

eu tentei:

```
function 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1)) = repeat_prod(n)

for n:
n = 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1));

end
```

Comment: o que é esse monte de pontinhos "...." ??

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta, é algo assim que você precisa:

```
function [P] = repeat_prod(n)
P = 1;
for i = 1:(n-1)
    P = P*(1+0.2*i);
end
end
```

Na definição da função, o que está entre `[]` é o que será retornado, o que está entre `()` são os inputs da função.
O for, é definido da seguinte maneira:

`for contador = inicio:passo:final`

porém você pode omitir o passo, que então será o valor padrão 1. Tanto para encerrar o for, como para encerrar a função inteira, você deve escrever `end`. Preste atenção ao último valor que vc quer iterar, se vai ser `n` ou `n-1`.